# Mybatis batch processing

Tags: java, mybatis, spring-mybatis

I have a table with 3+ millions records. And I need to read all those records from DB, send them for processing to kafka queue for other system to process. Then read results from output kafka queue and write back to the DB.
I need to read and write in sane portions otherwise I'm getting OOM exception at once.

What could be possible technical solutions to atchieve batch read and write operations with mybatis?
Neat working examples would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I will write pseudo code as I don't know mush about Kafka.

First at read time, Mybatis default behavior is to return result in a List, but you don't want to load 3 millions of object into the memory. This must be overridden by using a custom implementation of `org.apache.ibatis.session.ResultHandler<T>`

```
public void handleResult(final ResultContext<YourType> context) {
    addToKafkaQueue(context.getResultObject());
}
```

Also set the `fetchSize`of the statement (When using annotation based mapper: `@Option(fetchSize=500)`) if there is no value defined in Mybatis global settings. If let unset, this option relies by default on driver value, different for every DB vendor. This defines how much records at once will be buffered in the result set. E.g: for Oracle this values 10: generally too low because involving to much read operation from the app to the DB; for Postgresql this is unlimited (whole result set), then too much. You will have to figure out the right balance between speed and memory usage.

For the update:

```
do {
    YourType object = readFromKafkaQueue();
    mybatisMapper.update(object);
} while (kafkaQueueHasMoreElements());
sqlSession.flushStatement(); // only when using ExecutorType.BATCH
```

The most important is the `ExecutorType` (this is argument in `SessionFactory.openSession()`) either `ExecutorType.REUSE` that will allow preparing the statement only once instead of at every iteration with default `ExecutorType.SIMPLE` or `ExecutorType.BATCH` that will stack the statements and actually execute them only on flush.

Now remains to think about the transactions: this might involve commit 3 millions updates, or it could be segmented.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create separate instance of mapper for batch processing.

This might be helpful.

http://pretius.com/how-to-use-mybatis-effectively-perform-batch-db-operations/

Comment: Please add the information to your answer rather than just a link. Links can disappear.